# Replacing value from another column if it does not exist

Tags: mysql, case

I have 2 columns:

```
column_a                column_b
www.de.google.com/best  best
www.fr.google.com/free  free
www.google.com/fr/best  NULL
```

I've written a regexp which creates `column_b`, however, this regexp does not create the result if the link in `column_a` has localization after the `.com`. Now I want to add value `best` to the third row with `CASE`

```
CASE 
    WHEN column_a LIKE '%best%' THEN 'best'
    WHEN column_b LIKE '%free%' THEN 'free'
END AS type_2
```

This creates another column `type_2` and my result looks like this:

```
column_a                column_b    type_2
www.de.google.com/best  best        best
www.fr.google.com/free  free        free
www.google.com/fr/best  NULL        best
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
column_a                column_b    
www.de.google.com/best  best        
www.fr.google.com/free  free        
www.google.com/fr/best  best
```

How can I write a `CASE` statement which would not create another column but fill in the gaps in the `column_b` if it does not have a value?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE UrTableName
SET column_b =
 CASE 
  WHEN column_a LIKE '%best%' THEN 'best'
  WHEN column_a LIKE '%free%' THEN 'free'
 END
 WHERE column_b IS NULL
```

Something like that. Please note that I am using MS_SQL syntax. For MySql it might be different, but the logic is there